# How can I implement a dynamic count within R without using a for loop?

Tags: r

I want to distinctly count the number of customers who have purchased from the company between each SKU's first and last purchase date. This is after I have distinctly counted the number of customers for each SKU given in SQL (as well as finding the first and last purchase date),

I have code that successfully solves this problem; however, it uses a for loop and it is taking far too long because there are tens of thousands of SKUs. This is short example of what my SKU table looks like:

```
SKUID <- c('123', '456', '789')
NumberOfCustomers <- c(204543, 92703, 305727)
SKUFirstPurchase <- c('2014-05-02', '2014-02-03', '2016-05-13')
SKULastPurchase <- c('2017-09-30', '2018-07-01', '2019-01-09')

SKUCount <- data.frame(SKUID, NumberOfCustomers, 
                       SKUFirstPurchase, SKULastPurchase)
colnames(SKUCount) <- c('SKU', 'NumberOfCustomers', 
                        'FirstPurchase', 'LastPurchase')
```

Then I have another table that is about 6 million rows long, a select distinct of the sales date and the CustomerID that I call OrderTable. I can't summarize the distinct count on a day-to-day basis and sum them together because this would double count customers who have purchased on separate days. I have to re-calculate the distinct count with every FirstPurchase/LastPurchase permutation that I see in my SKUCount table. From there, I use the following code to calculate the distinct number of customers in the given time frame:

```
library(dplyr)

for (i in 1:nrow(SKUCount))
{
  SKUCount[i, c('DateCustomers')] <-
    sapply(OrderTable %>%
              filter(Date >= SKUCount[i,'FirstPurchase'],
                     Date <= SKUCount[i,'LastPurchase']) %>%
              select(CustomerID),
           function(x) length(unique(x)))
}
```

As I previously noted, this piece of code DOES work, but it's very slow (~0.5 second for each row). Is there a quicker way to calculate the distinct counts, or is there a more clever solution to my problem?

Comment: This sounds like an easy solution using any of the SQL packages available in R.  Can you use those?  With as much data as you are talking about, I'd be surprised if you aren't already taking advance of a RDBS.

Comment: Can you post an example of `OrderTable` so you have a completely reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    library("purrrlyr")
    library("dplyr")
    
#First creating the datasets including OrderTable (please correct me if I got it wrong!):
    SKUID <- c('123', '456', '789')
    NumberOfCustomers <- c(204543, 92703, 305727)
    SKUFirstPurchase <- c('2014-05-02', '2014-02-03', '2016-05-13')
    SKULastPurchase <- c('2017-09-30', '2018-07-01', '2019-01-09')
    
    SKUCount <- data.frame(SKUID, NumberOfCustomers, 
                           SKUFirstPurchase, SKULastPurchase)
    colnames(SKUCount) <- c('SKU', 'NumberOfCustomers', 
                            'FirstPurchase', 'LastPurchase')

    OrderTable <- data.frame(Date=c('2014-06-02', '2014-08-02', '2015-02-03', '2017-05-13'
    ,'2015-05-02', '2014-06-03', '2016-07-13', '2017-09-30', '2018-07-01', '2019-01-09'),
    CustomerID=c('121','212','3434','24232','121','124','212','131','412','3634'))

#changing factors to date
    SKUCount$FirstPurchase<-as.Date(SKUCount$FirstPurchase,format = "%Y-%m-%d")
    SKUCount$LastPurchase<-as.Date(SKUCount$LastPurchase,format = "%Y-%m-%d")
    OrderTable$Date<-as.Date(OrderTable$Date,format = "%Y-%m-%d")
        
#defining a function, named FUN, which limit the Date from OrderTable between 
#the two date arguments (FirstPurchase and LastPurchase) and returns the 
#distinct count of CustomerID's from OrderTable:
FUN <- function(FirstPurchase,LastPurchase){
              Rtrn<-OrderTable %>%
              filter(Date >= FirstPurchase,
              Date <= LastPurchase)  %>%
              summarize(n_distinct(CustomerID))
              as.numeric(Rtrn)
              }
```

## Next you want to take your dataset, SKUCount, and create a variable called DateCustomers by applying the function, FUN, to every row of it:

```
    SKUCount %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
       mutate(DateCustomers= FUN(FirstPurchase,LastPurchase))
      # Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
      # Groups: <by row>
      #   
      #   # A tibble: 3 x 5
      #   SKU   NumberOfCustomers FirstPurchase LastPurchase DateCustomers
      # <fct>             <dbl> <date>        <date>               <dbl>
      #   1 123              204543 2014-05-02    2017-09-30          6
      # 2 456               92703 2014-02-03    2018-07-01            7
      # 3 789              305727 2016-05-13    2019-01-09            5
```

Comment: Still very slow on my end, but nonetheless, this is another valid solution to the problem. Thank you very much!